# How to extract the month or number before the first / in a date?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like

```
date = "9/26/2017"

for %m in date:
    %m = i
    print(format(i, '02d'))
```

Is there a way to get the month number so that I can put a 0 in front of it?

I'm trying to take 9/26/2017 and output 09/26/2017.

Comment: `date.split('/')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you r reading date in the format you mentioned, then use

```
date = "9/26/2017"
d = date.split("/")
if len(d[0])==1:
    date="0"+date
print(date)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can split and zero-pad all fields in one line using `format` and unpacking arguments from conversion to integer of your splitted string:

```
"{:02}/{:02}/{:04}".format(*map(int,date.split("/")))
```

note: for only the first number, you could have used `date.zfill(10)` or to apply `zfill` on all terms with varying sizes:

```
"/".join(a.zfill(b) for a,b in zip(date.split("/"),[2,2,4]))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import *

d = '9/26/2017'
d = datetime.strptime(d,'%m/%d/%Y').date()
d = datetime.strftime(d,'%m/%d/%Y')
print d
```

---

```
09/26/2017
```